# How to convert a php string to jquery array?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

In php I push coordinates to an array in a loop:

```
        $lat = $location['lat'];
        $lng = $location['lng'];
        array_push($coordinates, $lat.",".$lng);
```

I then need those coords as a pair in jQuery.

```
  var coords = "<?php echo $coordinates; ?>";
  console.log(coords);
```

The above gives me:

```
40.836132854296686,8.404270310882566,40.7197406,8.563512299999957,41.36256133817761,2.131976960327165
```

But since I need them as a pair as I later do:

```
for (var a = 0; a < coords.length; ++a) {
    var pin = coords[a].split(',');
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pin[0], pin[1]);
```

I don't know who to convert that string in a pair array object. I thought of adding `[]` as a string when I push to array in php but it's very bad.

Basically I am looking for:

```
["55.695694737568054,37.5904788172536", "41.36256133817761,2.131976960327165", "40.836132854296686, 8.404270310882566", "40.7197406, 8.563512299999957"]
```

Thought of splitting every second comma in js as [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930243/split-on-every-second-comma-in-javascript) but I'm not sure is the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JSON

**PHP**

```
$lat = $location['lat'];
$lng = $location['lng'];
array_push($coordinates, [$lat, $lng]);
```

**JS**

```
var coordsJson = '<?php echo json_encode($coordinates); ?>';
var coords = JSON.parse(coordsJson)
console.log(coords);
// [[40.836132854296686,8.404270310882566],[40.7197406,8.563512299999957]]

for (var a = 0; a < coords.length; ++a) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(coords[a][0]), 
        parseFloat(coords[a][1])
    );
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `coords  = JSON.parse(coords);` if you want to do something with the array in Javascript.

Comment: it is giving me `var coords = [["40.836132854296686","8.404270310882566"],["40.7197406","8.563512299999957"],["41.36256133817761","2.131976960327165"]];`

Comment: and gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 18`

Comment: @rob.m check this line `array_push($coordinates, [$lat, $lng]);`

Comment: @User863 I'm not sure why it is wrong, I am using array_push($coordinates, [$lat, $lng]);

Comment: p.s. why parseFloat?

Comment: because your coords array has string values

Comment: @rob.m got it, enclose with a single quote (check last edit)

Comment: var coordsJson = '<?php echo json_encode($coordinates); ?>';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197140/discussion-between-rob-m-and-user863).